# How to deploy via azure release to VM?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to setup a release pipeline in azure devops which is supposed to deploy my web site to virtual machine, that is, update an existing web site already running on IIS.
I'm getting the following errors:

```
2021-02-25T20:47:55.4825268Z ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to IIS website.
2021-02-25T20:47:55.4836851Z ##[error]Error: The account 'RISK\PANDA' does not appear to be valid. The account was obtained from this location: 'system.applicationHost/applicationPools/DataConverterAPI'.
Error: Some or all identity references could not be translated.
Error count: 1.

2021-02-25T20:47:55.4839506Z ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe' failed with exit code 4294967295
```

[image]

here's my build pipeline .yml file content:

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  userPassword: 'myPass'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

IIS Web App Manage task .yml:

```
steps:
- task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'IIS Web App Manage'
  inputs:
    WebsiteName: DataConverterAPI
    WebsitePhysicalPath: '%SystemDrive%\DataConverterAPI'
    AddBinding: True
    Bindings: '{"bindings":[{"protocol":"http","ipAddress":"All Unassigned","port":"50352","hostname":"","sslThumbprint":"","sniFlag":false}]}'
    BasicAuthenticationForWebsite: true
    WindowsAuthenticationForWebsite: false
    ParentWebsiteNameForVD: DataConverterAPI
    ParentWebsiteNameForApplication: DataConverterAPI
```

IIS Web App Deploy task .yml:

```
steps:
- task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'IIS Web App Deploy'
  inputs:
    WebSiteName: DataConverterAPI
    TakeAppOfflineFlag: True
    XmlVariableSubstitution: True
```

someone help pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright I fixed this by changing the pool identity on which my application run to 'ApplicationPoolIdentity'

and sadly I don't know yet why it solved the problem, any comments would be appreciated